# Remove old carpet underlay stuck to concrete floor

Tags: concrete, flooring, carpet, underlayment

I am trying to remove the carpet and its underlay from the living room because it is very old (over 20 years I guess).

The underlay is terribly stuck to the concrete floor. It looks like it has been glued but as it is very old, it is crumbling and there also scraping it it is very hard.

I have tried with a long handle scraper, hot water, heater to warm it up, but it is very hard to remove it. In the last hour I have progressed only 30 cm!

Any suggestion of how to remove it? Any solvent which can soften it a bit?

Thanks

Comment: Pictures would help.  What's the blade on your scraper?  You can often buy/rent floor scrapers made for this purpose that have a sharp blade that works really well in these situations, assuming it's typical carpet glue.

Comment: Avoid toxic solvents. Depending on area size, a block of dry ice might help make it brittle, so that backing can be scraped off.

Comment: May want to consider a wire cup brush, like that which you can stick into an electric drill.

Answer (score 1):

A tungsten-carbide bladed scraper is the way I've removed glued-down carpet underlayment.

It's not easy, but it works. Steel scraper blades dull in short order.